# How to separate elements of a list which have a class?

Tags: html, css

Given a list of elements like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="favourite"></li>
  <li class="favourite"></li>
  <li class="favourite"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to create a gap between the list elements which have `.favourite` and those which don't.

Is there a way I can do this with CSS?

**Edit**
Assume that elements with the class `.favourite` are always forced to the top of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply a margin to a `li` that's not `.favourite`, that comes right after a `li.favourite`. You will need to use `:not()` in conjunction with an adjacent sibling selector, like this:

```
li.favourite + li:not(.favourite) {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

If it's not known in your actual markup whether classless elements come first or `li.favourite` elements come first, and you want to create a gap regardless of the order, extend the selector like this to cover both cases:

```
li.favourite + li:not(.favourite), li:not(.favourite) + li.favourite {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Use a left margin instead of a top margin if your list flows horizontally from left to right.

Comment: I noticed your edit so I added a constraint about the ordering of the list to my question.

Comment: I see it now. In that case you can simply use `li.favourite + li:not(.favourite)`.